# SQL Multiple foreign keys referring to the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have the following table **Student**:

```
Id  FirstName   LastName    State   Index   Year    Course1 Course2 Course3 Course4 Course5
622 Student622  LastName622 State17 62200   2   54  47  68  67  50
623 Student623  LastName623 State16 62300   3   17  99  37  99  32
624 Student624  LastName624 State2  62400   4   8   71  11  58  86
625 Student625  LastName625 State1  62500   2   39  75  33  77  17
626 Student626  LastName626 State15 62600   3   11  3   4   70  72
627 Student627  LastName627 State13 62700   2   84  77  65  62  76
628 Student628  LastName628 State13 62800   4   87  18  19  4   75
629 Student629  LastName629 State10 62900   2   96  67  14  97  31
```

The numbers in Course 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 are foreign key values that refer to the id of the following **Courses** table:

```
Id  Name    ProfessorId
1   Course 1    8
2   Course 2    14
3   Course 3    4
4   Course 4    3
5   Course 5    6
6   Course 6    2
7   Course 7    14
8   Course 8    4
9   Course 9    5
```

How can write script so that when i execute instead of foreign key numbers there is the Course name? Any thoughts?

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Welcome to the basics of every SQL language: [SQL Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) - [Joins (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: The real problem here is that your student table is not properly normalized. You have what is known as "repeating groups" in your table which violates 1NF. If you fix the design the query will be simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could LEFT JOIN to the Course table for each course id.

```
SELECT 
s.Id, s.FirstName, s.LastName, s.State, s.[Index], s.[Year],
c1.Name as Course1Name,
c2.Name as Course2Name,
c3.Name as Course3Name,
c4.Name as Course4Name,
c5.Name as Course5Name  
FROM Student s
LEFT JOIN Courses c1 ON c1.Id = s.Course1
LEFT JOIN Courses c2 ON c2.Id = s.Course2
LEFT JOIN Courses c3 ON c3.Id = s.Course3
LEFT JOIN Courses c4 ON c4.Id = s.Course4
LEFT JOIN Courses c5 ON c5.Id = s.Course5
```

Because those are all LEFT JOIN's, all the records of Student will be returned.
Even if some course id's aren't filled in.